# Vue 3 router doesn't work. I don't understand why

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm a beginner with vue (vue 3). I'm testing a mock vue application, and after testing the default homepage, i wanted to test how to make 2 (or more) different pages. However, what i do doesn't work, even though i'm following tutorials to the letter.

**Context**:

- *npm* v8.3.0
- *node* v17.3.0
- *vue* v3.2.25
- *vite* v2.7.2
- *vue-router* v4.0.12

**Expected result**: after having configured 2 routes, accessing route 1 gives me a webpage. Accessing route 2 gives me another page.

**Current result**: whichever route/path i try to access, i am always presented with the default/initial page (The "App" page use at the  initialization `const app = createApp(App)` ). My second page is never displayed. No error is displayed.

**Project structure**:

```
/src
  |- main.js
  |- components/
  |- router/
      |- router.js
  |- views/
      |- App.vue
      |- App2.vue
```

*main.js*:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './views/App.vue'
import router from "./router/router"

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

router.js:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter} from 'vue-router'
import App from '../views/App.vue'
import App2 from '../views/App2.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: App
  },
  {
    path: '/toto',
    component: App2
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue and App2.vue are vue files with noticably different content.

*App.vue*:

```
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/"> Home </router-link>|
    <router-link to="/toto"> Toto </router-link>
  </div>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Trying to make router work" />
</template>
```

(I omitted the  css code which i assume to be irrelevant to the issue)

**Issue**:

- When i access localhost:3000, i get the content of App.vue.
- When i access localhost:3000/toto, i get the content of App.vue.
- When i access locahost:3000/whatever (non-existent route), i get the content of App.vue.

I'm unable to find what i'm doing wrong.

**If it helps: vite.config.js**:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing to add the `router-view` component which will contains your routed components:

```html
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/"> Home </router-link>|
    <router-link to="/toto"> Toto </router-link>
  </div>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Trying to make router work" />
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```